# Css, gif in a table, 100% of viewport height

Tags: html, css, html-table, gif

I have a table, and inside an td tag an gif image:

```
<table id="wrapper">
  <tr>
     <td><img src="as.gif" width="auto" height="100%"></td>         
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tried thousands things to make the gif 100% of the viewport, but somehow it wont function! Here is my CSS:

```
html, body, #wrapper {
 height:100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
}

table {height:100%}

td {height:100%}

tr {height:100%}

#wrapper td {
text-align: center;
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried `img {height: 100%;}` ?

Comment: Seems to work as you have it. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/NwYg7/

Comment: my guess is that the context you are using it in is an HTML5 standard.  According to MDN, HTML5 img attribute of height only supports pixel values and not percentage as HTML4 did: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Img#attr-height

Comment: Seems that in an table it doesnt work,when i put the gif in an div it works. But how can i center this div?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
table tr td img { height : 100% }
```